# R query on '$'()

Tags: r

I created a data frame and am trying to access the columns in the data frame. The code is as shown below

```
df <- data.frame(n = c('A','B','C'),
                 mark_1 = c(23,25, 17),
                 mark_2 = c(45,46,50))

j <- paste('mark',1,sep="_")
j

f <- '$'(df,j)
summary(f)

n <- '$'(df,"mark_1")
summary(n)
```

When I run this code, this is what I get

```
    > j <- paste('mark',1,sep="_")
    > j
    [1] "mark_1"
    > f <- '$'(df,j)
    > summary(f)
    Length  Class   Mode 
         0   NULL   NULL 
    > n <- '$'(df,"mark_1")
    > summary(n)
       Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      17.00   20.00   23.00   21.67   24.00   25.00 
    >
```

Why is summary(f) not working? j is properly concatenated to "mark_1". Then why is the error happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use indexing as in `df[, j]`?

Comment: Continuing with the same question as above, I have 2 related queries: If I have 100 marks variables named as mark_1, mark_2 upto mark_100, is there any efficient method than using for(i in 1:100) {
  f <- paste('mark',i,sep="_")
  # some functionality code comes here #
} The second question is if the column mark_6 is missing the for loop comes out after i = 5 without processing mark_7 to mark_100. How do I get over this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

@TylerRinker showed you what to do instead.

...but the reason you can't use `'$'(df,j)` is that the dollar operator uses the second argument literally.

...so `'$'(df,mark_1)` would work fine. But you simply can't pass a variable to it. That's what `[` and `[[` are for:

```
df[,j]  # The j'th column
df[[j]] # Pretend df is a list of columns and get the j'th element
```

Comment: Good explanation.  I learned early on (maybe from R Inferno) to use indexing rather than the `$` guy because there were less surprises.

Answer (score 5):

Use indexing over the `$` as in:

```
df[, j]
summary(df[, j])
```

Answer (score 4):

`'$'(df,j)` is equivalent to `df$j` -- it looks at the name of the argument, 
rather than its value.
You can use `df[[j]]` or `df[,j]` or `'[['(df,j)` instead
(but avoid the last one, unless you want to make the code difficult to read).

```
df$j <- 1

# The "j" column
df$j
`$`(df,j)
`[[`(df,"j")
df[["j"]]
df[,"j"]

# The "mark_1" column
df[[j]]
df[,j]
`[[`(df,j)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use '$' if you applied it with `do.call`. `do.call` is useful in situations where you have the name of the function as a character rather than a language value. In this case it also evaluates the second argument, the list of dataframe and column name.

```
do.call('$', list(df, j))
[1] 23 25 17
```

That said, I think you are better off using '[[' or '[' which do the evaluation of the second argument as a matter of course.